# Python function to find prime numbers

Tags: python, function

This is not about finding the prime numbers, it is about how do I transfer the code into a function.

so I have this codes to help me to print the prime numbers from 2-100:

```
pnumber = [x for x in range(2, 101) if all(x % i for i in range(2, x))]
print(pnumber)
```

If I def this as a function, to find the prime numbers in a range:

```
 def p_number(a, b):
     pnumber = [x for x in range(a, b+1) if all(x % i for i in range(2, b))]
     print(pnumber)

 p_number(2, 100)
```

You can see that I use a to replace 2, and b to replace 100, and change the codes accordingly. But somehow, this won't work, it will output an empty list.

I wonder why?

Comment: Well that is logical: since the prime numbers are also in the `range(2,b)`. So if you test `3`, it will result in `3 % 3 == 0` and thus `all(..)` will fail...

Comment: Change `print(pnumber)` for `return(pnumber)`

Comment: why does `range(2, x)` change to `range(2, b)`?

Comment: @franciscosollima not the issue...

Comment: @asongtoruin You are right!!! What an idiot am I! But then, why b won't work here?

Comment: In the first example you write `if all(x % i for i in range(2, x))` but in the function you changed it to `if all(x % i for i in range(2, b))`

Comment: @jxie0755 Because you don't want to konw if `i` is indivisible by everything in `[a, b]` (which would include `i`), only if it is indivisible by everything *less than* `i`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Please notice that for i, the range(2, b) will actually exclude b, because range(2, b) is actually numbers 2 to b-1

Comment: @jxie0755: but `b` is the **upperbound** of your range, not of the number `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind that if you use the *upperbound* `b` in the check:

```
all(x % i for i in range(2, b))
```

this will **include all prime numbers up to `b`**. So `2`, `3`, `5`, etc. are also part of `range(2, b)` (given `b` is large enough). So that means that if we test for instance whether `3` is a prime, we will check for `i = 3`, and `3 % 3` is `0`, so that will fail.

Furthermore it will have a bad impact on performance. The idea of a prime test is to check all numbers up to but **excluding** the number. So a quick fix is:

```
def p_number(a, b):
    pnumber = [x for x in range(a, b+1) if all(x % i for i in range(2, x))]
    print(pnumber)
```

We can easily boost it further by using `int(sqrt(x))+1` instead of `x`:

```
from math import sqrt

def p_number(a, b):
    pnumber = [x for x in range(a, b+1) if all(x % i for i in range(2, int(sqrt(x))+1))]
    print(pnumber)
```

We can boost it further, for instance by only evaluating odd numbers (and add 2 to the result). But using *sqrt* will usually already result in a significant speedup.

Comment: I got it! if I put p_number(2, 100):
when I check each x, for example x=11, it will still iterate all the i from 2-100, which will of course include 11, then exclude 11 as the prime number. But if I use i's range (2, x), then for each x, the i's range will have a range <x

Comment: If ALL primes up to N are to be found, there is another way to speed it up in addition to the sqrt limit: test only with primes already found before.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to -

```
def p_number(a, b):
     pnumber = [x for x in range(a, b + 1) if all(x % i for i in range(a, x))]
     print(pnumber)
```

If you notice, you were iterating i from 2 to b, and not from 2 to x which is why you were getting an empty list.

Comment: I got it, the i's range is wrong. But I think you should not use i's range as (a, x) here, for i, we still want to go over every number starting from 2, up to b-1, not starting from the range that I was looking for the prime numbers.